# Use ts-node with TypeScript incremental build

Tags: typescript, ts-node

Is it possible to use `ts-node` with TypeScript 3.4+ incremental build options?

Answer (score 1):

In April, 2019, it looks like there is no way: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/811#issuecomment-480149019